# django datetime filter not working in template

Tags: django

i can't filter models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) in the template

in my template i used |date:"F d, Y" to filter date. it's showing raw string instead of filtering, however if i remove :"F d, Y" then it's working

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

template

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{
                post.date_posted | date: "F d, Y"
            }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

what is the possible reason for this and how to fix this ?

Comment: You should not add spaces around the pipe character, so it should be `{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's template language is a bit strict with respect to spacing. You should not add new lines between the curly brackets (`{{` and `}}`). Furthermore you should not add a space after the colon of `date:`:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```